# git pull fails with "Either the application has not called WSAStartup, or WSAStartup failed"

Tags: git, github, winsock, github-for-windows, wsastartup

I have just installed Windows 10, Visual Studio Community 2015, and [Git for Windows](https://git-scm.com/download/win). I also installed the latest Bitbucket and GitHub extensions.

Within Visual Studio I cloned my Bitbucket.com-hosted repository, and performed these operations successfully:

```
$ git --version
git version 2.19.2.windows.1

$ git pull
Already up to date.
```

But then when I tried to pull from another repository I got this error:

```
$ git pull git://github.com/aegif/CmisSync.git
fatal: unable to lookup github.com (port 9418) (Either the application has not called WSAStartup, or WSAStartup failed. )
```

I am able to ping github.com though.

How can I investigate and fix the problem?

Comment: I'm experiencing similar error if I try to start `$ git daemon` on my local machine. It fails with similar message for the WSAStartup call and failing to listen on port 9418. I think the issue may be similar, but I have not found any solution yet.
Edit: I'm also using the same git version - `git version 2.19.2.windows.1`

Answer (score 17):

For those who can't edit the URL, downgrading git to the previous version appears to work.

This seems to be an issue with git version `2.19.2.windows.1`

Comment: Correct. Associated GitHub issue: https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/1952

Comment: As mentioned in that GitHub issue, you can also download the [latest snapshots](https://wingit.blob.core.windows.net/files/index.html) which already contain a fix for this issue. Apparently there isn't going to be another proper release until some date in December.

Comment: I've switched to the `v2.20.0-rc2.windows.1` version available at https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/ and now it works properly.

Answer (score 15):

A low-tech workaround is to replace `git://` with `https://` in the URL.
The command then goes smoothly.

Warnings:

- It only works read-only, so if you might want to push to the repository any time in the future then use [PhillyAI's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53488391/226958) instead.
- Please note that while it currently works with GitHub, this trick might not work with other Git servers.

Answer (score 7):

It is a known bug in earlier versions of Git for Windows.

Upgrade/Install version greater than `2.20.0.`

You can check currently installed version with command `$ git --version`

Answer (score 1):

I found out there is one more solution, which is to navigate to the `.git` folder, edit the `config` file inside this folder changing

```
[remote "origin"]
        url = git://github.com/yourUsername/yourRepo.git
```

to

```
[remote "origin"]
        url = https://github.com/yourUsername/yourRepo.git
```

fixes the problem if one does not want to downgrade the git client