# NPM can't install webpack

Tags: npm, webpack

```
    D:\Programming\React\Project1>npm install --save-dev webpack
npm ERR! Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

This is the error i get when trying to install webpack. I had node version 10.50 now i am with node 11.10.0 and npm 6.7.0

I did cache clean --force , that didn't help. I installed react, react-dom babel but the webpack gives this error. I tryed installing it with --save-dev and without it, the result was the same. the log file is

```js
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'D:\\Program Files\\Node\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'D:\\Program Files\\Node\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'install',
1 verbose cli   '--save-dev',
1 verbose cli   'webpack' ]
2 info using npm@6.7.0
3 info using node@v11.10.0
4 verbose npm-session 85b41b11615ec8a8
5 silly install loadCurrentTree
6 silly install readLocalPackageData
7 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/webpack 377ms
8 silly pacote tag manifest for webpack@latest fetched in 413ms
9 timing stage:loadCurrentTree Completed in 804ms
10 silly install loadIdealTree
11 silly install cloneCurrentTreeToIdealTree
12 timing stage:loadIdealTree:cloneCurrentTree Completed in 3ms
13 silly install loadShrinkwrap
14 timing stage:loadIdealTree:loadShrinkwrap Completed in 179ms
15 silly install loadAllDepsIntoIdealTree
16 silly resolveWithNewModule webpack@4.29.4 checking installable status
17 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/@webassemblyjs%2fast 80ms
18 silly pacote version manifest for @webassemblyjs/ast@1.8.2 fetched in 88ms
19 silly resolveWithNewModule @webassemblyjs/ast@1.8.2 checking installable status
20 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/ajv-keywords 148ms
21 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/chrome-trace-event 149ms
22 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/acorn-dynamic-import 158ms
23 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/acorn 165ms
24 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/enhanced-resolve 162ms
25 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/eslint-scope 98ms
26 silly pacote range manifest for chrome-trace-event@^1.0.0 fetched in 177ms
27 silly resolveWithNewModule chrome-trace-event@1.0.0 checking installable status
28 silly pacote range manifest for ajv-keywords@^3.1.0 fetched in 184ms
29 silly resolveWithNewModule ajv-keywords@3.4.0 checking installable status
30 silly pacote range manifest for enhanced-resolve@^4.1.0 fetched in 193ms
31 silly resolveWithNewModule enhanced-resolve@4.1.0 checking installable status
32 silly pacote range manifest for acorn-dynamic-import@^4.0.0 fetched in 206ms
33 silly resolveWithNewModule acorn-dynamic-import@4.0.0 checking installable status
34 silly pacote range manifest for acorn@^6.0.5 fetched in 209ms
35 silly resolveWithNewModule acorn@6.1.0 checking installable status
36 silly pacote range manifest for eslint-scope@^4.0.0 fetched in 135ms
37 silly resolveWithNewModule eslint-scope@4.0.0 checking installable status
38 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/@webassemblyjs%2fwasm-edit 236ms
39 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/ajv 229ms
40 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/@webassemblyjs%2fhelper-module-context 245ms
41 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/json-parse-better-errors 57ms
42 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/@webassemblyjs%2fwasm-parser 249ms
43 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/loader-runner 68ms
44 silly pacote version manifest for @webassemblyjs/wasm-edit@1.8.2 fetched in 279ms
45 silly resolveWithNewModule @webassemblyjs/wasm-edit@1.8.2 checking installable status
46 silly pacote range manifest for ajv@^6.1.0 fetched in 273ms
47 silly resolveWithNewModule ajv@6.9.1 checking installable status
48 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/memory-fs 74ms
49 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/micromatch 71ms
50 silly pacote version manifest for @webassemblyjs/helper-module-context@1.8.2 fetched in 289ms
51 silly resolveWithNewModule @webassemblyjs/helper-module-context@1.8.2 checking installable status
52 silly pacote version manifest for @webassemblyjs/wasm-parser@1.8.2 fetched in 290ms
53 silly resolveWithNewModule @webassemblyjs/wasm-parser@1.8.2 checking installable status
54 silly pacote range manifest for json-parse-better-errors@^1.0.2 fetched in 106ms
55 silly resolveWithNewModule json-parse-better-errors@1.0.2 checking installable status
56 silly pacote range manifest for loader-runner@^2.3.0 fetched in 102ms
57 silly resolveWithNewModule loader-runner@2.4.0 checking installable status
58 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/node-libs-browser 78ms
59 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/neo-async 91ms
60 silly pacote range manifest for micromatch@^3.1.8 fetched in 96ms
61 silly resolveWithNewModule micromatch@3.1.10 checking installable status
62 silly pacote range manifest for memory-fs@~0.4.1 fetched in 100ms
63 silly resolveWithNewModule memory-fs@0.4.1 checking installable status
64 silly pacote range manifest for node-libs-browser@^2.0.0 fetched in 90ms
65 silly resolveWithNewModule node-libs-browser@2.2.0 checking installable status
66 silly pacote range manifest for neo-async@^2.5.0 fetched in 101ms
67 silly resolveWithNewModule neo-async@2.6.0 checking installable status
68 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/tapable 43ms
69 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/terser-webpack-plugin 52ms
70 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/webpack-sources 44ms
71 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/schema-utils 63ms
72 silly pacote range manifest for tapable@^1.1.0 fetched in 64ms
73 silly resolveWithNewModule tapable@1.1.1 checking installable status
74 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/watchpack 56ms
75 silly pacote range manifest for terser-webpack-plugin@^1.1.0 fetched in 65ms
76 silly resolveWithNewModule terser-webpack-plugin@1.2.2 checking installable status
77 silly pacote range manifest for webpack-sources@^1.3.0 fetched in 57ms
78 silly resolveWithNewModule webpack-sources@1.3.0 checking installable status
79 silly pacote range manifest for schema-utils@^1.0.0 fetched in 75ms
80 silly resolveWithNewModule schema-utils@1.0.0 checking installable status
81 silly pacote range manifest for watchpack@^1.5.0 fetched in 64ms
82 silly resolveWithNewModule watchpack@1.6.0 checking installable status
83 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/@webassemblyjs%2fwast-parser 48ms
84 silly pacote version manifest for @webassemblyjs/wast-parser@1.8.2 fetched in 57ms
85 silly resolveWithNewModule @webassemblyjs/wast-parser@1.8.2 checking installable status
86 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/@webassemblyjs%2fhelper-wasm-bytecode 71ms
87 silly pacote version manifest for @webassemblyjs/helper-wasm-bytecode@1.8.2 fetched in 77ms
88 silly resolveWithNewModule @webassemblyjs/helper-wasm-bytecode@1.8.2 checking installable status
89 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for long@git://github.com/dcodeIO/long.js.git#8181a6b50a2a230f0b2a1e4c4093f9b9d19c8b69 Error while executing:
89 silly fetchPackageMetaData undefined ls-remote -h -t git://github.com/dcodeIO/long.js.git
89 silly fetchPackageMetaData
89 silly fetchPackageMetaData
89 silly fetchPackageMetaData spawn git ENOENT
90 verbose stack RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
90 verbose stack     at RegExp.test (<anonymous>)
90 verbose stack     at isDepOptional (D:\Program Files\Node\node_modules\npm\lib\install\deps.js:405:45)
90 verbose stack     at failedDependency (D:\Program Files\Node\node_modules\npm\lib\install\deps.js:414:9)
90 verbose stack     at failedDependency (D:\Program Files\Node\node_modules\npm\lib\install\deps.js:430:9)
90 verbose stack     at failedDependency (D:\Program Files\Node\node_modules\npm\lib\install\deps.js:430:9)
90 verbose stack     at failedDependency (D:\Program Files\Node\node_modules\npm\lib\install\deps.js:430:9)
90 verbose stack     at failedDependency (D:\Program Files\Node\node_modules\npm\lib\install\deps.js:430:9)
90 verbose stack     at failedDependency (D:\Program Files\Node\node_modules\npm\lib\install\deps.js:430:9)
90 verbose stack     at failedDependency (D:\Program Files\Node\node_modules\npm\lib\install\deps.js:430:9)
90 verbose stack     at failedDependency (D:\Program Files\Node\node_modules\npm\lib\install\deps.js:430:9)
90 verbose stack     at failedDependency (D:\Program Files\Node\node_modules\npm\lib\install\deps.js:430:9)
90 verbose stack     at failedDependency (D:\Program Files\Node\node_modules\npm\lib\install\deps.js:430:9)
90 verbose stack     at failedDependency (D:\Program Files\Node\node_modules\npm\lib\install\deps.js:430:9)
90 verbose stack     at failedDependency (D:\Program Files\Node\node_modules\npm\lib\install\deps.js:430:9)
90 verbose stack     at failedDependency (D:\Program Files\Node\node_modules\npm\lib\install\deps.js:430:9)
90 verbose stack     at failedDependency (D:\Program Files\Node\node_modules\npm\lib\install\deps.js:430:9)
91 verbose cwd D:\Programming\React\Project1
92 verbose Windows_NT 6.1.7601
93 verbose argv "D:\\Program Files\\Node\\node.exe" "D:\\Program Files\\Node\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "--save-dev" "webpack"
94 verbose node v11.10.0
95 verbose npm  v6.7.0
96 error Maximum call stack size exceeded
97 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

How can i fix that guys please give advice.

Comment: Did you try `npm rebuild` ? Or delete the node_modules directory and do a `npm install` again?

Comment: i did with no result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Installing the previous version worked for me:

`npm install webpack@4.29.3 --save-dev`

Comment: I did the same after a friend gave the same advice. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue today. Looking at your log file on line 89 it says 'undefined' instead of git executable path.

Check git --version from commandline.

If it's not on path or 2.19.* **install latest git client** (currently git version 2.20.1.windows.1) please tell if it works.

update : adding my log for reference of anyone having same issue. My problem was caused by this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53477460/git-pull-fails-with-either-the-application-has-not-called-wsastartup-or-wsasta) in git client. After updating the git client I can install the latest webpack without a problem.

```js
329 silly resolveWithNewModule @webassemblyjs/floating-point-hex-parser@1.8.2 checking installable status
330 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for long@git://github.com/dcodeIO/long.js.git#8181a6b50a2a230f0b2a1e4c4093f9b9d19c8b69 Error while executing:
330 silly fetchPackageMetaData C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.EXE ls-remote -h -t git://github.com/dcodeIO/long.js.git
330 silly fetchPackageMetaData
330 silly fetchPackageMetaData fatal: unable to look up github.com (port 9418) (Either the application has not called WSAStartup, or WSAStartup failed. )
330 silly fetchPackageMetaData
330 silly fetchPackageMetaData exited with error code: 128
331 verbose stack RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
331 verbose stack     at RegExp.test (<anonymous>)
331 verbose stack     at isDepOptional (C:\Users\kmhatre\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\install\deps.js:405:45)
331 verbose stack     at failedDependency (C:\Users\kmhatre\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\install\deps.js:414:9)
331 verbose stack     at failedDependency (C:\Users\kmhatre\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\install\deps.js:430:9)
331 verbose stack     at failedDependency (C:\Users\kmhatre\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\install\deps.js:430:9)
331 verbose stack     at failedDependency (C:\Users\kmhatre\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\install\deps.js:430:9)
331 verbose stack     at failedDependency (C:\Users\kmhatre\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\install\deps.js:430:9)
331 verbose stack     at failedDependency (C:\Users\kmhatre\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\install\deps.js:430:9)
331 verbose stack     at failedDependency (C:\Users\kmhatre\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\install\deps.js:430:9)
331 verbose stack     at failedDependency (C:\Users\kmhatre\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\install\deps.js:430:9)
331 verbose stack     at failedDependency (C:\Users\kmhatre\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\install\deps.js:430:9)
331 verbose stack     at failedDependency (C:\Users\kmhatre\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\install\deps.js:430:9)
331 verbose stack     at failedDependency (C:\Users\kmhatre\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\install\deps.js:430:9)
331 verbose stack     at failedDependency (C:\Users\kmhatre\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\install\deps.js:430:9)
331 verbose stack     at failedDependency (C:\Users\kmhatre\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\install\deps.js:430:9)
331 verbose stack     at failedDependency (C:\Users\kmhatre\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\install\deps.js:430:9)
332 verbose cwd D:\exp\DjReact
333 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.14393
334 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\kmhatre\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "i" "webpack@latest"
335 verbose node v8.11.3
336 verbose npm  v6.8.0
337 error Maximum call stack size exceeded
338 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```